# Netbeans REST Tutorial not bringing me expected result

Tags: netbeans, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I've followed the REST Netbeans tutorial on http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html but the result I get when invoking get on customer service is:

```
<customers> 
   <customer> 
       <addressline1>111 E. Las Olas Blvd</addressline1> 
       <addressline2>Suite 51</addressline2> 
       <city>Fort Lauderdale</city> 
       <creditLimit>100000</creditLimit> 
       <customerId>1</customerId> 
       <discountCode> 
           <discountCode>78</discountCode> 
           <rate>0.00</rate> 
       </discountCode> 
       <email>jumbocom@gmail.com</email> 
       <fax>305-777-4635</fax> 
       <name>JumboCom</name> 
       <phone>305-777-4632</phone> 
       <state>FL</state> 
       <zip> 
           <areaLength>955.666</areaLength> 
           <areaWidth>923.556</areaWidth> 
           <radius>1876.766</radius> 
           <zipCode>33015</zipCode> 
       </zip> 
   </customer> 
   <customer> 
   ....
   </customer>
</customers>
```

Expected result would be same as in tutorial (uri on discountCode instead of data):

[Netbeans result](http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/70/websvc/rest/test-rest-raw.png)

How do I achieve that? I double-checked the tutorial several times. Using Netbeans 7.2.1 with mysql sample database, Glasfish 3.1.2.2. Also tried with Netbeans 7.1.2 but with same result.

Answer (score 0):

The output shown in the Netbeans tutorial has clearly nothing to do with that coming from the sample database, maybe could be related to some old version.
Carefully going through the code (`Customer` and `DiscountCode` classes) you can check that there is no `URI` attribute on the `Customer` class.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but looks like this is doable or was doable at some point and my question is how to do it out of the box with table relations.

Comment: Just add a calculated field to the `Customer` class and it will be added to the generated XML passed back to the client